# How can i make jquery, css external and internal styling work in my template?

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, django-crispy-forms

I have been working on a django project for some time now, but i'm having some problems with making external and internal css work, only inline css works, i have 2 questions

1. How can i make external css or internal css work and jquery? I tried running the collectstatic command, i added STATIC_URL, STATIC_DIR etc, i also added the css and jquery file path to my html
2. How can i beautify my registration/login forms? i already tried django_crispy_forms but i still didn't get the desired result.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

```
settings.py
    import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_DIR =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "website.User"
"""STATICFILES_DIR = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]"""


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    #My Apps
    #'avatar',
    'django_countries',
    'website',
    'djmoney',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'main.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'main.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

main html file

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" style="height: 100%;">
    <head>
        {% load static %}
        {% load filter %}
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
        <!-- Prism CSS -->
        <!---<link href="{% static "tinymce/css/prism.css" %}" rel="stylesheet"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/header.css' %}"/>
        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/website/css/header.css" type="text/css" media="screen" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'website:homepage' %}">Smart X</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end  " id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav  " >
      <li class="nav-item active ">
        <a class="nav-link " href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/account"><strong>Account</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Track Expense
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'website:create-expense' %}">Create Expense</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'website:check-expense' %}">Check Expense</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Budget
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'website:create-budget' %}">Create Budget</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'website:check-budget' %}">Check Budget</a>
        </div>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle btn" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          {{ request.user.last_name }} {{ request.user.email|gravatar:30 }}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'website:profile' %}">Profile</a>
           <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'website:settings' %}">Setting</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout"><strong>Logout</strong></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login"><strong>Login</strong></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/register"><strong>Register</strong></a></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<body style="position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%; ">
        {% if messages %}
          <ul class="messages">

            {% for message in messages %}
              <li class="{{ message.tags }}">
              {% if 'safe' in message.tags %}
                {{ message|safe }}
              {% else %}
                {{ message }}
              {% endif %}
              </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


my registration page html

    {% extends "website/header.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2" style="margin-top: 50px; border-style: groove;">
  <h1>Create New Account</h1>

        <form method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ form.first_name | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ form.last_name | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ form.email | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ form.password1 | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ form.password2 | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
          <button style="background-color: lightblue; color: black; " type="submit">SIGN 
        UP</button>
        </form>
        <p><strong>Already have an account? <a href="/login"><strong>Login</strong></a></strong></p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[This is what my login page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylVnU.png)

[My desired result, i want the login page and registration to look this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgkCe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a css folder inside your static folder and add your css files there. Link it on your base.html file as follows inside head tag (note: i named the css file as custom.css)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}"/>
```

and make sure that following settings are made in your settings file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Comment: I copied the the link as you stated above but still didn't reflect the css, i change custom.css to mycss.css but didn't work, only inline css styling is working

Comment: This worked like you added some magic to the code, thanks so much, i appreciate, i'd be glad if you could suggest me a way to make the jquery work on my templates

Comment: Similar way you can add js files also. This time it should be at the bottom part of the body tag